# Force changing the Site Title and add link

Tags: functions, title

I have the function below, but it's not actually changing the site title where it is called in my theme.

```
function blog_filter($string, $show) {
    if ( $show == "name" ) {
        $string = str_replace('Blog', '<a href="www.blog.com">blog.com</a>', $string);
    }
return $string;
}
add_filter('bloginfo', 'blog_filter', 10, 2 );
```

anyone knows why?

thank you

Comment: Silly question, are you sure your theme is using the `bloginfo("name")` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('option_blogname', 'filter_name');

function filter_name($string) {
   return str_replace('original', 'replacement', $string);
}
```

This code should work, as well as yours. But there's one catch, you have to use `get_bloginfo` like this:

```
echo get_bloginfo('name', 'raw');
```

If not, `bloginfo` sanitizes the output, and it eliminates the `<a></a>`. At the same time is someting good, because if not you would mess up a lot of things the in the dashboard.

Comment: Well, the theme uses get_blonginfo, not raw, so I guess bloginfo sanitizes the output and I can't make this work. thanks